# Named pipes in NSIS

Tags: nsis, named-pipes

Is there a possiblity to use named pipes from NSIS? If so how can you do it? I could not find anything on the web so I have big doubts this is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the windows API directly with the system plugin but for a big task it is usually better to write a custom plugin.

Comment: I assume you can pass data back from the plugin into NSIS, in a register or a variable, right?

Comment: @Liviu M: Yes, or if there is a lot of data your can pass a nsis function address to the plugin and call back into nsis code with data as it comes in...

Answer (score -1):

What do you want to use named pipes for?
You can create simple plugin which will perform all tasks you need.